# Access a page's variable from a custom directive

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a directive and a page(simplified version of my actual code). When myMethod gets called via an event I need myPages isTrue method to become true, but I am unsure how to access the page's variable from the directive. How can I do this? PS. I am using a framework which is based on Angular2 called Ionic2.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[mySelector]'
})

export class myDirective {

    constructor() {
    }

    myMethod() {
        //Make myPage's isTrue equal to true;

    }

}


@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/myPage/myPage.html',
    directives: [myDirective]
})
export class myPage{

    isTrue= false;

    constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: Would be better if could say and show , 1. How do u used directive in myPage? 2. How does your .html look like?

Comment: Read the [tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom event within your directive with the `@Output` decorator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mySelector]'
})
export class myDirective {
  @Output()
  customEvent:EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  myMethod() {
    this.customEvent.emit(true);
  }

  // Just a way to call the myMethod method
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myMethod();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

In the component, the event could be catch this way to update the `isTrue` property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div mySelector (customEvent)="updateIsTrue($event)"></div>
    <div>isTrue = {{isTrue}}</div>
  `,
  directives: [ myDirective ] 
})
export class AppComponent { 
  isTrue= false;

  updateIsTrue() {
    this.isTrue = true;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr as a sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/yuFTwMqYVNJ2awcK02gf?p=preview.

Another option would be to inject the component into the directive. For this you need to leverage the `forwardRef` function, since class hoisting isn't supported:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[mySelector]'
})
export class myDirective {
  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => AppComponent)) private host: AppComponent) {

  }

  myMethod() {
    this.host.isTrue = true;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myMethod();
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/jOlEWZzilTId3gruhu9B?p=preview.